# What does "A iff B iff C" mean?

Tags: logic

I am asked to show A iff B iff C. I know to prove A iff B, I need to show (if A, then B) and (if B, then A). However I don't understand what A iff B iff C is, as well as what logical relationships I need to show to fully prove this.

Comment: Just need to prove A implies B, B implies C and C implies A.

Comment: It is analogous to $x=y=z$.

Comment: It's a short and sloppy way of saying "show $A$ iff $B$ and $B$ iff $C$".

Comment: Emphasis on *sloppy*.

Answer (score 1):

It means "prove $A$, $B$, and $C$ are [materially equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_equivalence)."  The long way is to show any two of $A \iff B$, $B \iff C$, and $C \iff A$.  A common shorter way is to show $A \implies B$, $B \implies C$, and $C \implies A$ (so that the reverse implications follow by applying [hypothetical syllogism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypothetical_Syllogism) to the other two).

More generally, it is sufficient to prove a collection of implications and equivalences such that, for any given implication, $ x \implies y$ for $x,y \in \{A,B,C\}$, either $x \implies$ y or $x \iff y$ are already proven, or $x \implies y$ may be deduced by (possibly repeated) hypothetical syllogism applied to some set of implications or equivalences in the set.  A much shorter way to say this: the graph of implications is a [strongly connected digraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component).

In a context of complete formalistic rigour, one should literally prove all six implications.  However, it is almost universally accepted that once a sufficient set of implications and equivalences is proven having the property that it may be completed to the full set of implications by (repeated, if necessary) hypothetical syllogism, you are done.

Answer (score 0):

It could mean one of several things.

First, it could mean that $A$, $B$, and $C$ are all *logically equivalent* statements: in every logically pssible interpretation of these statements, they are either all true, or all false.

More formally, using $\Leftrightarrow$ as our meta-logical symbol for logical equivalence, this would be saying that $A \Leftrightarrow B$, $B \Leftrightarrow C$, and $A \Leftrightarrow C$

We could write this a bit sloppily as $A \Leftrightarrow B \Leftrightarrow C$, but you have to be careful with that, for the $\Leftrightarrow$ is not an associative operator ... indeed it isn't much of an operator at all; it just expresses a meta-logical relationship.

A second thing it could mean (and in most mathematical contexts this is likely the intended meaning) is that all three statements are equivalent relative to some domain. For example, within the domain of natural numbers, one can say that '$x$ is even iff $x^2$ is divisible by $4$ iff $x^2$ is divisible by $2$': 
These three statement statements are not *logically* equivalent, but we can say they are *mathematically* equivalent: within the domain of natural numbers, no matter what we choose for $x$: either all three statements are true or all three are false.

Formally, we could symbolize this as saying that all three statements $A \leftrightarrow B$, $B \leftrightarrow C$, and $A \leftrightarrow C$ are true in the domain under consideration, where $\leftrightarrow$ is the material biconditional. Or, since in the example we have a free variable $x$, that $\forall x (A(x) \leftrightarrow B(x))$, $\forall x (B(x) \leftrightarrow C(x))$, and $\forall x (A(x) \leftrightarrow C(x))$ are all derivable from the axioms defining the domain.

Third and finally, but by far least likely, is that the statement means $A \leftrightarrow B \leftrightarrow C$.  As it turns out, the material biconditional $\leftrightarrow $ *is* an associative operator, and so this is a meaningful statement, but (maybe somewhat surprisingly), it is *not* the case that $A \leftrightarrow B \leftrightarrow C$ is a logically valid statement if and only if all three statements are equivalent to each other, i.e. '$A \Leftrightarrow B \Leftrightarrow C$', and that is because $A \leftrightarrow B \leftrightarrow C$ is true if and only if an even number of the three statements are false. Thus, for example, if $A$ and $B$ are false, but $C$ is true, then $A \leftrightarrow B \leftrightarrow C$ is true ..... which is unlikely what the speaker intended to express.